# visible button in grid

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

my gridpane is :
[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="569.0" prefWidth="794.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/2.2" fx:controller="com.controller.test">
  <children>
    <GridPane layoutX="10.0" layoutY="270.0" prefWidth="775.0" rotate="0.0">
      <children>
        <Button fx:id="btn1" mnemonicParsing="false" prefWidth="67.0" rotate="0.0" text="btn1" GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="0" />
        <Button fx:id="btn2" mnemonicParsing="false" prefWidth="67.0" rotate="0.0" text="btn2" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="0" />
        <Button fx:id="btn3" mnemonicParsing="false" prefWidth="67.0" rotate="0.0" text="btn3" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="0" />
        <Button fx:id="btn4" mnemonicParsing="false" prefWidth="67.0" rotate="0.0" text="btn4" GridPane.columnIndex="3" GridPane.rowIndex="0" />
      </children>
      <columnConstraints>
        <ColumnConstraints maxWidth="594.0" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="69.0" />
        <ColumnConstraints maxWidth="594.0" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="69.0" />
        <ColumnConstraints maxWidth="558.0" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="67.0" />
        <ColumnConstraints maxWidth="507.0" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="507.0" />
      </columnConstraints>
      <rowConstraints>
        <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
      </rowConstraints>
    </GridPane>
  </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

i need the result like below image when visible(false) for btn1,btn2
[image]

i use scene builder. thanks

Answer (score 1):

In addition to making the components invisible by setting the visible property to false ('visible="false"'), you have set the managed property to false (managed="false").But with explicit 'ColumnConstraints' in your fxml, 'managed=false' will not have effect. So you may want to avoid using ColumnConstraints  and instead use GridPane child component's properties to set dimensions.